How to disable fading unused methods in Visual Studio 2022 17.12.0?
I updated my "Visual Studio Community Edition 2022" to version 17.12.0. Now all code of C# private and protected methods are ugly. Please, see image.

How I can disable it? I want equal appearence for private and public methods in C#.
Here is my settings for fading at TextEditor/C#/Advanced:

I tried to find a setting that would change the color of the private methods, but I couldn't. I also tried many other themes, but the result was the same. By the way, many good color themes have now started to look much worse. In some of them half of the code is completely grayed out.

Visual Studio typically only does this for unused methods. So the fact the methods are public and private per-se doesn't affect this. Except, given the name of the functions here I suppose these may be test methods and usually those have to be public so the test is discovered and therefore the function is used. I would assume once you add a call to test2() from test1() it will appear exactly the same as test1() as it is then used.

Ok, how to disable it for "unused" methods?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unused-private-member-IDE0051-fading-e/10781612

It will be considered as potentially used if you make it public, even when not called anywhere. Fading is actually very useful as it allows you to safely delete unused members.

As mentioned in the DC link provided in the comments above, this feature request has been reported by relevant users, and you can go to the link and vote. It should be noted that Microsoft may only consider adding this feature if enough users report this request. If there is any follow-up progress, please also update this post.

Thanks Hans Passant for comment. Solution available at this link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unused-private-member-IDE0051-fading-e/10781612

To disable the rule for your entire project, add the following to your
.editorconfig file on root projects alongside “.sln”:
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0055.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0052.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0051.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0044.severity = none



I have created a small extension to disable this fading: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2024/11/22/customizing-unreachable-code-fading-in-visual-studio-with-visual-commander/
